# Addition and subtraction with TBookmark object

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

My question is how I can do operations like addition and subtraction with TBookmark object. For example, let's say I want to go 4 rows higher in the dbgrid:

```
MyPoint:=Query1.GetBookmark;
...
//MyPoint:=MyPoint-4;
Query1.GotoBookmark(MyPoint);
```

Here the commented line is wrong. It produces a "Operator not applicable to this operand type" message. The question is what I should write in place of the commented line. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot perform arithmetic directly on a bookmark. To do what you ask you need to go to the bookmark, and then move relative to that:

```
Query1.GotoBookmark(MyPoint);
Query1.MoveBy(-4);
```

If you wish, you could then save another bookmark representing that record.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in my case because I refresh the query and going to the bookmark can produce a "Record not found" error in case some records have been deleted.

Comment: Well that is only to be expected.

Comment: @Rick77 what did you expect? Didn't know where to go, but from this point moving 4 back leeds to somewhere in nowhere. After a refresh everything could happen, also no data at all.

Comment: @Rick77, This answers your question perfectly. I don't understand your comment. You initially stated that you have reference to the bookmark (MyPoint), and wanted to move -4 records. You loose your bookmarks after your refresh your dataset.

Comment: @Rick77 maybe this http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/dbgrid_row_pos.htm will help you in this case

Comment: Just to add that using a bookmark has nothing to do with what you want. Unless you intend to jump back to "MyPoint" there is no need for `Query1.GotoBookmark(MyPoint)`, and the short answer to your question is `Query1.MoveBy(-4)` - this will get you -4 records from your `current` position.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!